# Replacing Class of <a> </a> Base On Status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to change the class of anchor tag of my html and php code.
This is the screenshot:
[image]

And below is php code for that screenshot

Here is my PHP code:

```
  <?php echo "<td>{$id}</td>" ?>
       <?php echo "<td>{$ontrack_websiteName}</td>" ?>
       <?php echo "<td>{$ontrack_url}</td>" ?>
       <?php echo "<td>{$ontrack_geography}</td>" ?>
       <?php echo "<td>{$ontrack_Comment}</td>" ?>  
       <?php echo "<td><a class='btn btn-success' href='status_db.php?id={$id}&status={$ontrack_status}'>
        <span>$ontrack_status</span></a>
       </td>" ?>  
        <?php echo "<td width='100px'><a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' href='archiveProcess.php?id={$id}' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-save-file' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>
    <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete_websiteOntrack.php?id={$id}' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></td>" ?>
```

There is two values coming from "Status" column. One is "Enable" and another is "Disable". When user click "Enable" green link. It will change the value in DB as "Disable" and show "Disable". When it show "Disable", i would like to change the background as "btn btn-danger" class so that the background will become red.

But currently. It only show as green background as show below:
[image]

Pleae kindly help me. I trying to do different way but always failed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do something like below

on success and When it show "Disable" :

```
$( "#btn-change" ).removeClass( "btn-success" );
$( "#btn-change" ).addClass( "btn-danger" )
```

Let `btn-change` is an id of that button.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first of all you should not use so many `<?php ?>` tags.

What you are actually looking for is a simple if-statement:

```
<?php 
    //if status is enable, set button class to success
    if($ontrack_status == "Enable"){
        $btn_class = "success";
    }else{ 
        $btn_class = "danger"; //else set it to danger
    }
//put btn class into the string:
echo "<td>{$id}</td>
      <td>{$ontrack_websiteName}</td>
      <td>{$ontrack_url}</td>
      <td>{$ontrack_geography}</td>
      <td>{$ontrack_Comment}</td>
      <td> <!-- set button class here-->
        <a class='btn btn-{$btn_class}' href='status_db.php?id={$id}&status={$ontrack_status}'>
            <span>$ontrack_status</span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width='100px'>
        <a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' href='archiveProcess.php?id={$id}' role='button'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-save-file' aria-hidden='true'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete_websiteOntrack.php?id={$id}' role='button'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span>
        </a>
      </td>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get why you're using a new echo and opening and closing PHP on each line. You could just do

```
<?php

echo "<td>{$id}</td>
   <td>{$ontrack_websiteName}</td>
   <td>{$ontrack_url}</td>...
```

Apart from that, to answer your question, you'll need to use an [if-statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). So for example:

```
if($ontrack_status == 'Disable') {
  echo "<td><a class='btn btn-success' href='status_db.php?id={$id}&status={$ontrack_status}'>
    <span>$ontrack_status</span></a>
   </td>"
}else{
  echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger' href='status_db.php?id={$id}&status={$ontrack_status}'>
    <span>$ontrack_status</span></a>
   </td>"
}
```

A nicer solution would be to use [shorthands](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

```
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-".($ontrack_status == 'Disabled' ? 'success' : 'danger')."' href='status_db.php?id={$id}&status={$ontrack_status}'>
    <span>$ontrack_status</span></a>
   </td>"
```

Comment: Thank You. It is working fine now .. will eliminate php tagsss :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var status = <?= $ontrack_status ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {   
    if(status == "Enable"){
     $("a").addClass("btn-success");
     $("a").removeClass("btn-danger");
    } else {
    $("a.status").addClass("btn-danger");
     $("a.status").removeClass("btn-success");
});
```

```
<a class="status " href=""></a>
```